# MongoDB find closest match

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if it is possible to access a document in MongoDB via closest match.
e.g. my search query always contains:
`name`
`country`
`city`

Following rules are in place:
1. `name` always has to match
2. if either `country` or `city` is present, country has a higher priority
3. if `country` or `city` does not match only consider this document, if they have the default value (e.g. for String: "")

example Query:
`name` = "Test"
`country` = "USA"
`city` = "Seattle"

Documents:

```
db.stuff.insert([
{
    name:"Test",
    country:"",
    city:"Seattle"
},{
    name:"Test3",
    country:"USA",
    city:"Seattle"
},{
    name:"Test",
    country:"USA",
    city:""
},{
    name:"Test",
    country:"Germany",
    city:"Seattle"
},{
    name:"Test",
    country:"USA",
    city:"Washington"
}
])
```

It should return the 3rd document

thanks!

Comment: Which out of 2 documents it should return: the one with matching name, or with matching city?

Comment: The closest one. If it finds a match with 2 properties being correct that one, otherwise returning both would be an option. Maybe if no exact match return a list of documents with closest match first

Comment: How about adding a weight to your documents based on the presence or absence of those field and use it to query your documents?

Comment: "May be" ? It would be extremely hard to answer, if you don't know what you need in the result.

Comment: Yep, @Styvane. That's exactly the way I thought. Just needed some guidelines from OP how to build the weights, but apparently the scope has changed to return an ordered list of "almost matched" documents.

Comment: "Maybe" cause currently I'm trying to assess if this is possible at all. But yes you are right, the fields have a priority. So if there is only one match, the name goes first

Comment: @Dimitri, it is possible, and I am happy to help, but you need to update the question with priority for all 7 permutations, and clarify whether you need a single document, or a list of documents.

Comment: @AlexBlex thank you for your patience :) I've updated my question. Hopefully this helps. If you need more information, please let me know

Comment: @Dimitri so actually fields **exist** in documents but their values do not match? Can you clarify phrase *if either country or city is present* - some of fields not exist in document?

Comment: @Dimitri, Could you add which 3 documents you expect, and in which order, if order matters. If I understand your rules, the result should have only 2 documents: #1 and #3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering uncertain requirements and contradicting updates, the answer is rather a guideline addressing the "Is it possible at all" part.

The example should be adjusted to meet expectation.

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
    {$match: {name: "Test"}}, // <== the fields that should always match
    {$facet: {
        matchedBoth: [
            {$match: {country: "USA", city: "Seattle"}},  // <== bull's-eye
            {$addFields: {weight: 10}}                    // <== 10 stones
        ],
        matchedCity: [
            {$match: {country: "", city: "Seattle"}},   // <== the $match may need to be improved, see below 
            {$addFields: {weight: 5}}            
        ],
        matchedCountry: [
            {$match: {country: "USA", city: ""}},
            {$addFields: {weight: 0}}                  // <== weightless, yet still a match
        ]
        // add more rules here, if needed
    }},
    // get them together. Should list all rules from above  
    {$project: {doc: {$concatArrays: ["$matchedBoth", "$matchedCity", "$matchedCountry"]}}},
    {$unwind: "$doc"},              // <== split them apart
    {$sort: {"doc.weight": -1}},    // <== and order by weight, desc
    // reshape to retrieve documents in its original format 
    {$project: {_id: "$doc._id", name: "$doc.name", country: "$doc.country", city: "$doc.city"}}
]);
```

The least explained part of the question affect how we build up facets. e.g.

`{$match: {country: "", city: "Seattle"}}`

matches all documents where country explicitly present and is an empty string.

It very well might be

`{$match: {country: {$ne: "USA"}, city: "Seattle"}}`

to get all documents with matching name and city and any country/no country, or even

`{$match: {$and: [{$or: [{country: null}, {country: ""}]}, {city: "Seattle"}]}}`

etc.

Comment: I think there's a need to add $group as a last stage to get distinct docs. @Alex

Comment: @wael32gh, yes, good point. If documents match conditions in multiple facets you will need to pick one with the highest weight I guess. Really depends on the conditions if they are not mutually exclusive. If the OP was after the "closest match" `$limit: 1`  would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {name:"Test"}},
  {$project: {
      name:"$name",
      country: "$country",
      city:"$city",
      countryMatch: {$cond: [{$eq:["$country", "USA"]}, true, false]},
      cityMatch: {$cond:[{$eq:["$city", "Seattle"]}, true, false]}
  }},
  {$match: {$and: [
      {$or:[{countryMatch:true},{country:""}]},
      {$or:[{cityMatch:true},{city:""}]}
      ]}},
  {$sort: {countryMatch:-1, cityMatch:-1}},
  {$project: {name:"$name", country:"$country", city:"$city"}}
])
```

Explanation:

First match filters out docs which don't match name (because rule #1 - name should match).

Next projection selects doc fields plus some information about country and city matches. We will need it to further filter and sort documents.

Second match filters out those documents which don't match both country and city and don't have default values for these fields (rule #3).

Sorting documents moves country matches before city matches as rule #2 states. And last - projection selects required fields.

Output:

```
{
    _id: 3,
    name : "Test",
    country : "USA",
    city : ""
},
{
    _id: 1,
    name : "Test",
    country : "",
    city : "Seattle"
}
```

You can limit query results to get only closest match.

Comment: I failed to see how this answered OP's question